# Weird exception in calling a method in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I'm getting an exception with this trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.something.activity.SomeActivity.onCreate(SomeActivity.java:53)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    ... 11 more
```

And in line 53 of the given activity, I'm just calling a method of SomeActivity, which is something like this:

```
50 @Override
51 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
52     ...
53     populateItems();
54     ...
55 }
```

How can I get a `NullPointerException`  on calling line of a method? Is my log reporter drunk or what? BTW I'm pretty sure about the line of the code and whether the version who got the exception and the given code is exactly the same.

Comment: is that the complete stacktrace related to the exception?

Comment: put your full oncreate method

Comment: put your `populateItems()` method

Comment: You have not posted enough information to allow us to figure out what is going wrong, but on the face it, it looks like your source code and the stacktrace are out of step.

Comment: *"BTW I'm pretty sure about the line of the code and whether the version who got the exception and the given code is exactly the same."* - Pretty sure is not good enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, a method is not a field. Most likely it seems like you compiled your code, ran it and then afterwards changed some code. Then the stacktracke will of cause lead you wrong.

Answer (score 1):

put your full onCreate method

check these:
-call setContentView(layout) before populateItems()
-in findViewById(item) , item must be in it's container layout

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `main_layout` that you are using in `setContentView(R.layout.main_layout)` is correct layout that should include all the items/views you are using in `populateItems()`, then you can get each item in `populateItems()` by `findViewById(R.id.item_id)`, otherwise you will get `NullPointerException`